# Where should I ask a question about mythology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was going to ask a mythology question (about the ancient Romans) on [history.stackexhange](http://history.stackexchange.com), but then I looked at [their FAQ:](https://history.stackexchange.com/faq)

> It is not [for questions] about:
>
> ## ...
>
> - Mythology

Where would be the proper place to ask that? Is there an appropriate SE site?

Comment: Probably the Christianity site

Comment: @random I don't think that would work...

Comment: @random I meant the Roman religion, as in Jupiter and Neptune, as opposed to Roman Catholic.

Comment: Wow, what an unexpected thing to find in their FAQ. I *definitely* would have assumed that mythology would be on topic there. I mean, you have to draw the line somewhere on what is history, but mythology seems like a good candidate for inclusion. I'm sure there was a Meta post about it at some point.

Comment: @CodyGray I searched MetaSO for [`mythology`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mythology) and nothing came up relevant, even that.

Comment: You could ask on the [Philosophy.SE Meta](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/) whether they'd be interested in such questions. I couldn't make that call.

Comment: Ah, I meant the History site meta. [Is it appropriate to ask questions about mythology here?](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/123) Steve's comment makes the most sense to me. For example, it's almost impossible to separate medieval Scandinavian history from Norse mythology.

Comment: I am +1 for Philosophy.SE, though ask on Meta first to make sure.

Comment: I was [hoping to get it included](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8442/should-the-latin-proposal-cover-roman-and-greek-mythology) in the [Latin Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48247/latin-language-usage) proposal.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is now a [Mythology.SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/), <strike>currently in private beta. A Community Manager has notified us (the users there) that we can expect to enter public beta within the next week, pending review by the team.</strike> now in public beta!

We do indeed have a [roman](/questions/tagged/roman) tag, with a decent amount of questions. We also have a [greek](/questions/tagged/greek) tag for questions about Greek mythology; it is very popular.

For more information, check out [the Area 51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology). You can also see [Commitment](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307?phase=commitment) and [Definition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307?phase=definition) information there.